# Disable browser prompt when using ADB to open an URL

Tags: google-play-store, adb, shell

I'm trying to open an URL using the ADB command:

```
  ./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d URL
```

When I have multiple browser support applications, I'm trying to open this using google play store. Is there a way I can set this to open this URL by google play store app and nothing else? The URL is a app store app url. Its an automation where there might be apps installed back to back. In case I download a firefox for android app, I don't want the device to prompt me to open the URL using the available apps but stick to google play store app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways.

The simpler one is to use a legacy `market://details?id=com.shadowburst.showr` URL instead of `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr`. No browser will offer to open a `market://` URL, but it's still possible that another installed app will do so.

The more complex way is to explicitly specify what *activity* you want the intent to open. This way, there's no possibility of another app responding to the intent. However, it's possible that a future Play Store update will change what activity you need to name: very old devices that only have Android Market won't work with this command.

You can find the package and activity name using an app such as [Stanley](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.xgouchet.packageexplorer). (In this case, you need to go to Stanley's settings to let it show system apps.)

The command to do what you want is

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.LaunchUrlHandlerActivity https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shadowburst.showr
```

Comment: The second option using com.android.vending/... works perfect. When I used the first option I was prompted to open with play store or mobgenie app. Thanks a lot